# Will singleton class be duplicated if is not directly referenced?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reference, singleton, duplicates

Let's say I have the DLL assembly **A**, where I in the right way have implemented the singleton pattern. Let it be the class `Manager` with his `Instance` static property returning the only instance.

Let's say then that I have created the DLL assembly **B** where the class `Controller` is declared and this assembly references to the **A** and the `Controller` class uses the `Manager`, okay.

Finally, there is a console application **C** where I got the only reference to the assembly **B** and several instances of the class `Controller`.

Now, the question. Will those instance share the `Manager` class between them or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, the question. Will those instance share the Manager class between them or not?

Yes, they will share the same instance because all those assemblies live in a single AppDomain. A different instance will be used if you create another application **D** (web, console, desktop, ...) where you reference the other assemblies and attempt to access the `Manager.Instance`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: yes, as the `Manager` is correctly implemented singleton.